# Sass Compilation Error

Tags: terminal, sass, compass

I am trying to compile my Sass file, but keep getting this error in my terminal:

> error sass/app.scss (Line 60: File to import not found or unreadable:
>   custom.

This happened after:

```
cd to the containing folder
sass --watch `sass:css`
```

What did I do wrong? What steps should I take? Do I need to use Compass to use Sass?

Comment: Where is the custom sass or scss file? What is your folder structure?

Comment: I put the sass folder directly into my foundation folder with the website i am trying to build. Within that is my app.scss file. The foundation folder is on my desktop.